# how does this Fibonacci solution work in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Would really appreciate an explanation on the given solution below. How does JavaScript 'store' the s variable as an array as I would think it continually would get overwritten as the `s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);` line doesn't get hit until after the recursion?

From my understanding JavaScript reads left to write then up to down, so it will never hit the push line until after it has gone through all cycles of `s`?

How its storing it an array?

```js
function fibonacci(n) {
  if (n === 1) {
    return [0, 1];
  } else {
    var s = fibonacci(n - 1);
    s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);
    return s;
  }
}
console.log(fibonacci(8));
```

Comment: The inner most method return an array i.e. `[0, 1]` so in simple term `s` is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your start the script with `n=8` the variable `s` will be created:

```
var s = fibonacci(n - 1);
```

The function will be recurcively called until `n` becomes equal to 1. In this step function returns array with two elemens:

```
 return [0, 1];
```

This array is returned to `s`. In next steps the array length will be increased by `push()` method:

```
s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);
```

So, the function step by step exits from recursion.

Answer (score 1):

let me explain you the execution of code,
at the first time, you call `fibonacci(8)`

```
//8>1 so it will go to the else part
    var s = fibonacci(n - 1); // again it will call fibonacci(7)
    s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);
    // here s is [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13] so s.push(s[8-1]+s[8-2])) is [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21]
    return s; //here s is [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21]

//7>1 so it will go to the else part
    var s = fibonacci(n - 1); // again it will call fibonacci(6)
    s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);
   // here s is [0,1,1,2,3,5,8] so s.push(s[7-1]+s[7-2])) is [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13]
    return s; //here s is [0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13]
.
.
.
.

//2>1 so it will go to the else part
    var s = fibonacci(n - 1); // again it will call fibonacci(1)
    s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);
    // here s is [0,1] so s.push(s[2-1]+s[2-2])) is [0,1,1]
    return s; //here s is [0,1,1]


//1 is not > 1 so it will go to the if part 
    return [0, 1]; // again it will call fibonacci(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code code be written as a simple iteration, which might make it more clear:

```
function fibonacci(n) {
  var s = [0, 1];
  while (n > 1) {
    s.push(s[s.length - 1] + s[s.length - 2]);
    n -= 1;
  }
  return s;
}
```

In this case, the recursive version isn't much of an improvement, in my opinion.